# Doctrine2: lazy loading not working for inversed relationships

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got 2 tables, say post and post_blacklist, whose simplified yml info is below. The post_record tabvle has a FK to the post table. When the post_blacklist table contains a record, this means that the post is blacklisted.

I'm trying to retrieve all posts that are not blacklisted.

I can see 2 solutions:

- big where in clause (probably not so good performance-wise)
- left join, which is implemented below

  ```
  $qb->select('p')
          ->from('MyBundle:Post', 'p')
          ->leftJoin('p.PostBlacklist', 'pbl')
         ->where('pbl.idPost IS NULL');
  ;
  ```

The left join above works, except that to make it work I had to declare an inverse relationship between post and post_blacklist (called PostBlacklist).

Because of that inverse relationship, everytime I retrieve a Post entity, I've got an additional left join to the post_blacklist table automatically added by Doctrine 2.

I managed to track it down to the file doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php:

```
$this->_selectJoinSql .= ' ' . $eagerEntity->table['name'] . ' ' . 
$this->_getSQLTableAlias($eagerEntity->name, $assocAlias) .' ON ';
```

**My question**: why is that and can I accomplish what I want without having that extra join added by Doctrine ??

**PostBlacklist entity:**

```
  type: entity
  table: post_blacklist
  fields:
    idBlacklist:
      id: true
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_blacklist
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
    idPost:
      type: integer
      unsigned: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_post    
  oneToOne:
    Post:
      targetEntity: Post
      cascade: {  }
      mappedBy: null
      inversedBy: PostBlacklist
      joinColumns:
        id_post:
          referencedColumnName: id_post
      orphanRemoval: false
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Post entity**

```
  type: entity
  table: post
  fields:
    idPost
      id: true
      type: string
      length: 35
      fixed: false
      nullable: false
      column: id_post
      generator:
        strategy: IDENTITY
  oneToOne:
    PostBlacklist:
      targetEntity: PostBlacklist
      mappedBy: Post
  lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the fetchMode to "lazy" or "extra_lazy"? It should only retrieve the entity if it is requested.  For the PostBlacklist:

```
oneToOne:
  Post:
    # ...
    fetchMode: "lazy"
```

and for the Post:

```
oneToOne:
  PostBlacklist:
    # ...
    fetchMode: "lazy"
```

You can check [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/guilhermeblanco/orm-dont-kill-your-db-developers-do) for more information about fetch modes.

Comment: Yep I tried, I also tried to use extra_lazy. But it's not taken into account, as it is an inversed relationship. The lazy/extra_lazy only seem to work from the owning side.